# How to find intersection set of (or a line equation between) two planes?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to find intersection set of two planes?

When the planes are given in the form $ax+by+cz=d$.

This is in order to find a line segment that forms between two non-parallel planes that collide. And that can be used to e.g. construct new planes.

Comment: and the other plane?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The form is the same.

Comment: can we set $$Ax+By+Cz=D$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner What you mean set?

Comment: The system of two equations with 3 unknowns

$$\begin{cases}ax+by+cz=d\\a'x+b'y+c'z=d' \end{cases}$$

has an infinite number of solutions depending of 3-2=1 parameter

Comment: a formula for the second plane

Comment: @mavavilj: It would improve your Question to add some context, such as where the problem arises or what makes it interesting to you.  This would help Readers supply a response that fits your application.

Comment: Also, this doesn't look like [tag:vector-analysis]. More like [tag:linear-algebra] if you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the planes are given in the form: 
\begin{align*}
a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=d_1 \\
a_2x+b_2y+c_2z=d_2 \\
\end{align*}

All solutions $(x,y,z)$ that fulfil both equations can be found by using [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

Another way to find all $(x,y,z)$ is to rewrite them to 
\begin{align*}
a_1x+b_1y+c_1z-d_1=0 \\
a_2x+b_2y+c_2z-d_2=0 \\
\end{align*}
and then set them to be equal: 
$$a_2x+b_2y+c_2z-d_2 \overset{!}= a_1x+b_1y+c_1z-d_1$$
Now again sort and solve.

If the planes are not parallel, expect a line. That means an infinite amount of solutions with some parameter $t∈ℝ$ in it.

edit: You can find an example with numbers [here](http://mathinsight.org/intersecting_planes_examples)

Comment: Yeah it was simple, I was just thinking too complicately.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the two planes $P_1$ and $P_2$ (assumed to be in algebraic form) which are defined as

$$P_1: a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=d_1$$
$$P_2: a_2x+b_2y+c_2z=d_2$$

Our goal is to rewrite one of them into parametric vector form, by determining three points on the plane, which we assume not to lie on one line. Let us rewrite $P_2$ by using the three points interpreted as vetors $(x,y,z)^T$ given as $\boldsymbol{\alpha}=(d_2/a_2,0,0)^T$, $\boldsymbol{\beta}=(0,d_2/b_2,0)^T$ and $\boldsymbol{\gamma} = (0,0,d_2/c_2)^T$. The bold faced formatting is used to denote vectors.

So the equation of the plane $P_2$ in parametric vector form is given by:
$$P_2: \boldsymbol{x}=\mu(\boldsymbol{\beta}-\boldsymbol{\alpha})+\lambda(\boldsymbol{\gamma}-\boldsymbol{\alpha})+\boldsymbol{x}_0$$

Now, plug the components of this vector $\boldsymbol{x}$ into the parametric equation $P_1$ and you will get a relationship for $\mu$ and $\lambda$, which we will call $\lambda = f(\mu)$. Substitute this into $P_2$ and you have the equation for the line of intersection $L$.

$$L: \boldsymbol{x}=\mu(\boldsymbol{\beta}-\boldsymbol{\alpha})+f(\mu)(\boldsymbol{\gamma}-\boldsymbol{\alpha})+\boldsymbol{x}_0$$

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong.

2 planes are characterized by their normal vectors $\vec n, \vec n'$.

1) $\vec n$ is parallel $\vec n'$, the planes are either identical, or do not intersect.

2) Assume $\vec n$ is not parallel to $\vec n'$, I.e. the planes intersect.

Their intersection is a straight line $ \vec r(t)$.

Direction vector $\vec d$ of this line:

$\vec d = \vec n × \vec n'$, cross product.

We need one point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ common to both planes.

Plane 1: $ax_0+by_0+cz_0 = d$.

Plane 2: $a'x_0+b'y_0+c'z_0=d'$.

$(a-a')x_0+(b-b')y_0+(c-c')z_0$

$= d-d'$.

Any triple $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ satisfying the above equation will do.

Finally:

$\vec r(t) = (x_0,y_0,z_0) +t \vec d$.